# Is it possible to stop one sub with another midway through it's process? VB

Tags: vb.net, forms, loops, user-interface

I'm working on forms with vb and I have a process where I need to be able to cut it off at any point, sort of like an emergency stop, and then be able to resume it. I've managed to make the code for the actual traffic lights (which need to be able to be cut off) though it's very repetitive and I've only just started coding so apologies about that.

It looks like this right now

```
Public Class Form1
Dim x = True

    Private Async Sub btn_start_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_start.Click

        While x

            If Not x Then
                Exit While
            End If
            Await Task.Delay(5000)
            SB_yellow.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            If Not x Then
                Exit While
            End If
            Await Task.Delay(3000)
            SB_green.BackColor = Color.Green
            SB_yellow.BackColor = Color.White
            SB_red.BackColor = Color.White
            If Not x Then
                Exit While
            End If
            Await Task.Delay(10000)
            SB_green.BackColor = Color.White
            SB_yellow.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            If Not x Then
                Exit While
            End If
            Await Task.Delay(3000)
            SB_yellow.BackColor = Color.White
            SB_red.BackColor = Color.Red
            If Not x Then
                Exit While
            End If
            Await Task.Delay(5000)
            SA_yellow.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            If Not x Then
                Exit While
            End If
            Await Task.Delay(3000)
            SA_red.BackColor = Color.White
            SA_yellow.BackColor = Color.White
            SA_green.BackColor = Color.Green
            If Not x Then
                Exit While
            End If
            Await Task.Delay(10000)
            SA_green.BackColor = Color.White
            SA_yellow.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            If Not x Then
                Exit While
            End If
            Await Task.Delay(3000)
            SA_yellow.BackColor = Color.White
            SA_red.BackColor = Color.Red

        End While
    End Sub

 Private Sub btn_stop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_stop.Click
        x = False
        MsgBox("stop")
    End Sub
End Class
```

SB and SA are setb and seta traffic lights

Currently, when I run my form and I press btn_stop it waits until it finishes changing the traffic light to another colour, and then it stops the while loop.
I was using threading.thread.sleep() before but I got rid of that because it shut down the UI, so I ended up using await and it works for now, but I'm not sure on how, if at all possible, to cut off the code/pause it.
I chose a while loop because I couldn't figure out another way to make the code loop.

For further context (in case it helps), my assignments asks that we make a program that runs a sequence of predetermined traffic lights for set a and set b, which I managed to make, and then to be able to override it in order to set both sets of lights to red in case of an "emergency", and then safely restart the lights afterwards. Finally to develop a mobile app that can control the traffic lights.

> •  Provide the correct operational sequence for the Set A traffic lights
> •   Provide the correct operational sequence for the Set B traffic lights
> •   Provide an option to override the operational sequence and change both sets of traffic lights to red, e.g. to stop all traffic on both sides of the roadworks when delivery vehicles need to enter or leave the repair area
> •   Be able to safely restart the traffic light operational sequence, e.g. after the override has been triggered or at any other time.
> •   Develop a mobile app that will control the traffic lights remotely.

> In developing the software solution system, you should consider enhanced user experiences and how it would deal with any unexpected events that may occur.

Currently at a wall and not sure what to do. I'm aware I can clean up the code and make it look nicer, this is more of just a first draft/attempt at it and I didn't intend to get this far.
Any help is greatly appreciated! As well as any tips or habits to develop.

Comment: I think your current approach can work.  You need to add checks inside your loop for whether the button has been triggered (e.g. have it flip a form-level variable).  If you need the delays, you may need to provide for cancellation; `Task.Delay` has an overload that will take a cancellation token so that you can break out of the wait early.  Keep the cancellation source as a form-level variable, then you can pass the token to the delays and trigger the cancel from the button event.

Comment: You might want to consider consolidating your color changing code into a single routine (e.g. called as `SetLightColor(Color.Red)`), it would make your sequence code a little more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have access to timer control since you are creating a forms. I think using a it will help you in this.

I changed x to make a counter for seconds and it will be useful when determining what is the current time

```
Dim x As Integer = 0

Private Sub btn_start_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_start.Click
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

The stop button will stop the timer, reset the counter, and set the traffic light to stop

```
Private Sub btn_stop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_stop.Click
    Timer1.Stop()
    x = 0
    SB_green.BackColor = Color.White
    SB_green.BackColor = Color.White
    SB_red.BackColor = Color.Red

    SA_green.BackColor = Color.White
    SA_yellow.BackColor = Color.White
    SA_red.BackColor = Color.Red

    MsgBox("stop")
End Sub
```

The Timer will set the color of the traffic lights depending on what you've set it.

The case statement is a placeholder only. I don't think using case statement will be the best for this scenario because the delay won't be customizable

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Select Case x
        Case 0
            SB_green.BackColor = Color.Green
            SB_yellow.BackColor = Color.White
            SB_red.BackColor = Color.White
            SA_green.BackColor = Color.White
            SA_yellow.BackColor = Color.White
            SA_red.BackColor = Color.Red
        Case 6
            SB_green.BackColor = Color.White
            SB_yellow.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            SB_red.BackColor = Color.White
            SA_green.BackColor = Color.White
            SA_yellow.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            SA_red.BackColor = Color.White
        Case 9
            SB_green.BackColor = Color.White
            SB_yellow.BackColor = Color.White
            SB_red.BackColor = Color.Red
            SA_green.BackColor = Color.Green
            SA_yellow.BackColor = Color.White
            SA_red.BackColor = Color.White
        Case 13
            x = 0
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    x += 1

End Sub
```